# Android Spinner Force closed

Tags: android, android-spinner

I try to add a Spinner to my activity, no error in the code so far but everytime I run it on an Android Simulator, it's force close. Please Help.

```
package com.nhan.quach.random_number_creator;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class giac_mo extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView text;
    int backButtonCount = 0;
    String[] s = {"1","2","3","4"};
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (backButtonCount >= 1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tap Back again to exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        backButtonCount++;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_giac_mo);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    NavigatetionDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigatetionDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

    drawerFragment.setup((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout), toolbar);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+s[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

}

Spinner Code Part

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_giac_mo);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+s[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

I try to get rid of all the code which deal with Spinner and the Activity works fine, event with the Spinner in the .xml so I pretty sure that my .xml is not the problem here, so you can just focus on the code itself.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the logcat output from when the app is crashing so we can see what is causing it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find `Spinner` when activity object is created. You will get `null` in this case. Move below lines into `onCreate` method after call to `setContentView`

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
```